# Long Press and Release in Appium

Tags: appium

I need to long press a button for a few secs and release, I have the following code,

```
WebElement recordButton = driver.findElement(By.id("xxxxxx/record_button"));
        TouchActions action = new TouchActions(driver);
        action.longPress(recordButton);
        action.release();
        action.perform();
```

I get the below errors

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver cannot be cast to
>   org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen

What I'm I doing wrong.

Trace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen
```

**Appium v1.8.1**

Dependencies used:

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.internal.TouchAction;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

import java.net.URL;

Comment: Try declaring your WebDriver as `AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>` and use AndroidElement instead of WebElement.  Only a suggestions, not positive it will work.  Also, doesn't longPress have a duration parameter?  You might also need to do a .build() before the .perform()

Comment: Doesn't work I tried both the suggestions

Comment: Are you using Maven? If yes, could you provide your dependencies?

Comment: I have updated the question with the details

Comment: We need to know your versions as well, for Appium, Selenium at least.

Comment: It is also worth providing a stacktrace since we need to know where exactly it was thrown (Class, method, line)

Comment: @AlexeyR. I have added the version and the trace

Comment: What you have added is not a trace. It is just an exception message. Trace means showing the call stack for the place where exception occurred (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors). Also you shouw only AppiumDriver version. But what is the version of your AndroidDriver?

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyR. for pointing that out, I managed to fix it using a different approach, I will post here. Pleas check

Comment: As per Appium 1.10.0 and io.appium.java_client - 7.0, the original issue still exists and the provided solution still works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below worked for me,

```
TouchAction action = new TouchAction(driver).longPress(longPressOptions().withElement(element(recordButton)).withDuration(Duration.ofMillis(10000))).release().perform();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Used Dependencies,

> import static
>   io.appium.java_client.touch.LongPressOptions.longPressOptions; import
>   static io.appium.java_client.touch.offset.ElementOption.element;
>   import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;

Comment: You should mark your own answer as the "accepted answer"

Comment: You can't mark your answers directly atleast in my case, I will do it once the needed time elapses which is now in 5 hrs

Comment: @BillHileman person can not accept it's own answer. Never.

Comment: @Eliyahu I believe the green checkmark on this answer, where the original poster answered and his own question and has now accepted his own answer proves that you can indeed accept your own answer.  I've done it to my own questions when I've later discovered a solution so that it does not still show up as unresolved.

Comment: OK, but I'm sure this does not give points

Answer (score 0):

**Working solution** with:
Python 3.x, Appium 1.22.3-4, Mac M1

- *Long press* on iOS can be achieve using snippet

> **TouchAction(driver).long_press(element).release().perform()**